# PostgreSQL merge COUNT and GROUP BY result

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
select type, created_at::date , count(type)
from txns
group by created_at::date, type
order by created_at::date;
```

The above SQL query gives the following output:

```
  type   | created_at | count 
---------+------------+-------
 full    | 2017-05-20 |     2
 virtual | 2017-05-20 |     2
 full    | 2017-05-21 |     1
 virtual | 2017-05-21 |     1
 full    | 2017-05-22 |     3
```

How can I group the above result by `created_at` to get the following output:

```
 created_at | full_count | virtual_count
------------+-----------------
 2017-05-20 |     2     |  2
 2017-05-21 |     1     |  1
 2017-05-22 |     3     |  0
```

I want to get the `full` and `virtual` type count by `created_at` in a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this without a CTE/subquery as:

```
select created_at::date,
       sum( (type = 'Full')::int ) as cnt_full,
       sum( (type = 'Virtual')::int ) as cnt_virtual
from txns
group by created_at::date
order by created_at::date;
```

Postgres often materializes CTEs, so this could even have a slight performance advantage.

Note:  You can also use `filter` in more recent versions of Postgres:

```
select created_at::date,
       count(*) filter (where type = 'Full') as cnt_full,
       count(*) filter (where type = 'Virtual') as cnt_Virtual
from txns
group by created_at::date
order by created_at::date;
```

Comment: this solution is better, and "type" shouldn't be in the group.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
with so as (
select type, created_at::date , count(type) from txns group by created_at::date, type order by created_at::date
)
 select
  created_at
, sum(case when type = 'full' then count else 0 end) full_count
, sum(case when type = 'virtual' then count else 0 end) virtual_count
from so
group by created_at;

 created_at | full_count | virtual_count
------------+------------+---------------
 2017-05-20 |          2 |             2
 2017-05-21 |          1 |             1
 2017-05-22 |          3 |             0
(3 rows)
```

Comment: You are Awesome Thanks!
Waiting for other result other wise i will accept it Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then two types, and in further processing you can deal with hstore:

```
WITH q AS ( SELECT type, created_at::date , count(type) FROM txns GROUP BY 1,2)
SELECT created_at, hstore(array_agg(type), array_agg(count::text))
FROM q GROUP BY 1;
```